# WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 188) for input, but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (188,)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Can someone help me to fix this? tensorflow is really annoying.

WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 188) for input KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 188), dtype=tf.float32, name='input_9'), name='input_9', description="created by layer 'input_9'"), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (188,).

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be missing a dimension. Try batching your data:

```
train_set = train_set.batch(32)
```

Comment: After add `batch(32)` I got `ValueError: "logits" and "labels" must have the same shape, received ((None, 25) vs (None, 1)).`.

Comment: Your output layer of your model needs to look like this: `tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid`)